# UserType / Hibernate / JodaTime - where to set UserType global properties?

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime, usertype

I'm using the `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime`  class from UserType 3.0.0.RC1 to map a JodaTime `DateTime` to Hibernate. [The Javadocs](http://usertype.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/jadira/usertype/dateandtime/joda/PersistentDateTime.html) for the class mention that there are 'databaseZone' and 'jvmZone' properties which I would like to set, but I cannot find anything in the UserType documentation that indicates how to do this. I found [this thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1003520) which seems to imply that these are set by XML similar to the following:

```
<prop key="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes">true</prop>
<prop key="jadira.usertype.databaseZone">jvm</prop>
```

I tried adding these to my hibernate configuration, but that just gave an error. Does anyone know where this configuration needs to go? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those settings can indeed be placed in the hibernate configuration, as like the following:

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SOME_DATABASE</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>

    ...

    <property name="jadira.usertype.databaseZone">UTC</property>
    <property name="jadira.usertype.javaZone">UTC</property>

</session-factory>
```

Turns out I was actually referencing an old version of the UserType library by mistake, which didn't support those properties. D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

Those settings need to go into your `persistence.xml`.

An example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10239179/59015)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I don't have a persistence.xml file; in the project I am working on we have got all of these properties configured in the 'session-factory' bean managed by Spring. Nice to know the alternative is there though.